# Why don't SSI's work for me?

Tags: html, apache, include, server-side-includes

I'm trying to include one html file into another. I'm coding on the MAMP stack. I assume SSI's are automatically permitted. I type 
      `<!--#include virtual="header.html" -->` 
in the body of one html file, the other file is called header.html, and they are both in the same folder. I even tried calling the file header.shtml instead. None of this works. It's frustrating.

The code isn't included. I'm including a form and a navigation bar, but they don't appear.

Comment: Please provide more details - what happens exactly? What do you mean by "doesn't work"? - and some code.

Comment: look into the source code. Is the "virtual" code still there? In that case, you need to check your config, because SSIs are not being parsed.

Comment: If you fixed the problem, either post the solution for the benefit of others, or delete the question.

Comment: Nope, I haven't fixed the problem yet.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume SSI's are automatically permitted

That's a very big assumption. SSIs will only work if you've got mod_include loaded. You also need to enable the filter for the relevant files, e.g.

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
```

...and of course ensure that Includes are not overridden elsewhere in the config.

Did you read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html)?